# How handle Previous Sqlite Db Data while updating Apk in android?

Tags: android, database

I have already uploaded one apk file for one of the project, now i am updating apk with updated column in my database table,so i dont want to loss previous apk db table data.

so please help me out from this.

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

[Use `SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and implement `onUpgrade()`. You are passed the old and new database schema versions, and you can then perform an in-place modification of your database structure (e.g., run `ALTER TABLE` statements using `execSql()` on the supplied `SQLiteDatabase` instance).